# Browsers (Chrome/FF) incorrectly scaling list items when zoomed

Tags: html, css, browser, webkit, margin

At zoom level 100%, everything matches up. But when the zoom level is modified, then (I think) the margin of list items are not scaled correctly. It seems to stay the same size for a few zoom levels, then "jump" to the next correct value. I believe this is due to the browsers rounding off the margin, so 1.1px is still 1px, 1.4px is still 1px, and then there is a sudden jump from there.

Example webpage where this behavior can be shown: http://thisiswhyimsane.com/

Look at the 'Take a look' button and the thumbnails beneath when the page is scaled.

EDIT: More testing of the behavior shows that the zooming is correct for 50%, 100%, 150%, 200%, etc but not anywhere in between. This strongly suggests a rounding issue in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Webkit end up rounding the values to gain performance.

Comment: could you give a source on that webkit deliberately rounded it for performance?

Comment: @gladoscc It was a teacher who told me that once. I tried to find the documentation but no success. If I find something I'll try to remember this post. Cheers